# javascript check if array contains multiple elements in a row

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, row

I would like to know if its possible to search an array for multiple items which are in a row, something similar to below. I have done it with separate includes, but this does not allow me to tell if the elements are in a row or near each other.

The array is not sorted and the numbers have to be in a defined order. Near being in a row, specifically 3. So (23,34,45) being searched within (12,23,45,34) would be false.

Thanks

```js
var num = [];
num.push(12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90);

if(num.includes(23,34,45)){
  print('found');
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you'll have to write logic to check if they are sequential. Your exact requirements aren't clear - is the array always sorted? Can the numbers appear in any order? What is "near" each other?

Comment: The array is not sorted and the numbers have to be in a defined order. Near being in a row, specifically 3. So (23,34,45) being searched within (12,23,45,34) would be false. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "near"?  They're either consecutive or they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, I hope I understood your question correctly.

```
function foo(num1, num2, num3, arr) {
    var exists = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == num1 && arr[i+1] == num2 && arr[i+2] == num3) {
            exists = true;
        }
    }

    console.log(exists);
}

var array = [12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90];

foo(23,34,45,array);
```

Comment: @Andreas In one of his comments OP said "specifically 3".

Answer (score 1):

One more way using ES6 Set() feature:

```js
    var arr = [12,23,34,12,45,56,67,78,89,90];
    var set = new Set();
    arr.forEach(function(i){ set.add(i) });
    var foundCount = 0;
    
    var func = function(a){
        a.forEach(function(item) { 
          var oldLength = set.size; 
          set.add(item); 
          var newLength = set.size; 
          
          if(oldLength === newLength) { 
            foundCount++;
          }               
        });
        console.log('found ' + foundCount) 
    }
    
    var arr2 = [12, 34, 45];

    func(arr2);
```